# Select last n rows matching a criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL and I'm trying to write a query to filter values and retrieve the last n records matching that criteria.

I have data that has a MainAssemblyIdnty, Barcode, Cellname. For the Cellname field, there are 3 cells; cell 1, cell 2, and cell 3. I'm trying to retrieve the last n records for just cell 3. I've tried using TOP and MAX functions, but the results displayed only shows 30 results. I also looked in to the LIMIT function but it doesn't seem to be supported with my version of SQL. Check out the codes below:

```
SELECT TOP 100 (Barcode) FROM Results WHERE Cellname= 'Cell 3'

SELECT  (Barcode)
FROM Results
WHERE IIf(Cellname='Cell 3',MainAssemblyIdnty,null) > 
    (
    Select Max(MainAssemblyIdnty) - 100 
    From Results 
    WHERE Cellname='Cell 3'
    )
```

It appears to take the last 100 records total (doesn't matter which cellname) then filter by cellname, but I want it to filter by cellname then give 100 records of only that cellname.

Answer (score 1):

TOP is the correct way to do this, and the only reason your attempt may not have worked is that you didn't supply an ORDER BY.   Which means, get ANY 100 rows...not get the LAST 100 rows.

If you use `MainAssemblyIdnty` to determine which rows are "last", then you just needed to do this:

```
SELECT TOP 100 (Barcode) 
FROM Results 
WHERE Cellname= 'Cell 3' 
ORDER BY MainAssemblyIdnty DESC
```

EDIT based on comments:   I'm pretty sure you are misinterpreting the results you are seeing.   You're seeing less than 100 rows returned and you think that means that the query is FIRST getting the top 100 rows and THEN filtering those rows to only those with `Cellname = 'Cell 3'`.

That, however is not the case.  SQL doesn't work that way.  The filter is applied FIRST, and THEN the results are limited by the TOP 100.   If you get less than 100 rows, that means there are less than 100 rows in the ENTIRE TABLE that match the filter.

If you doubt it, simply because there are "thousands of records in the table", test it with this simple query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Results 
WHERE Cellname= 'Cell 3'
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I want. Sorry if the above explanation wasn't worded the best. The result of this script results in 5 rows. The 'TOP 100' is taking the last 100 records from the table and filtering so that only Cell 3 results show up. In this case, it appears that in the last 100 records in the table, 95 were from Cell 1 or 2. I want there to actually show 100 records for Cell 3 if that makes sense

Comment: It sounds like you're saying you want a result of 100 records for Cell 3 even if there are less than 100 records for Cell 3 in the table.   If that's true, then no, it doesn't make any sense.   Where do you want the 100 records to come from if they aren't in the table?   Or maybe you're misinterpreting the results.   I can assure you that if the query above only returns 5 rows, that means there are only 5 rows in the table where Cellname = 'Cell 3'.

Comment: There are thousands of records in the table and I only want to limit it to the last 100 (or whatever number I choose). Ultimately, I want to determine if there are reoccurring failures and be able to fix them if there are so many within the last n amount of parts for each cell

Comment: See my edit to my answer.  It doesn't matter how many rows are in the table.  Apparently there are less than 100 rows that have 'Cell 3'.

Comment: I see what happened. I am using Ignition software and there was a sample limit checkbox set to 5 when I ran my query and therefore only giving me 5 values. When I unchecked it, it returned 100 values. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You should have an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT TOP 100 (Barcode)
FROM Results
WHERE Cellname = 'Cell 3'
ORDER BY MainAssemblyIdnty DESC ;
```

For performance, you want an index on `Results(Cellname, MainAssemblyIdnty DESC)`.

If you only have 30 rows, then you will only get 30 results.  It is not clear what you really intend in this case.

Comment: There are thousands of records in the table and I only want the most recent 100 records that match the criteria of Cellname = 'Cell 3'. The 30 rows from earlier came from taking the last 100 records for cells 1, 2, and 3 and then filtering records with Cell 3 so that only 30 records showed. In other words, out of the last 100 records entered, only 30 came from cell 3.

Answer (score 0):

You mention in several responses that you are looking for the 100 "most recent" rows where cellname = 'Cell 3'

First Do you have any kind of a timestamp?  If so then use TOP and order by the timestamp DESC.  For better performance you may be advised to create a nonclustered index on that column and the cellname column, like this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX 
    IX_RESULTS_CELLNAME_TIMESTAMP
ON [RESULTS]
(
    [CELLNAME]
    ,[TIMESTAMP]
)
```

;

If you don't have a timestamp, then is the MainAssemblyIdnty column a sequential number?

If so, then you can do exactly as Gordon suggested above.  For performance, you should consider creating the nonclustered index above but with MainAssemblyIdnty as the second indexed column.

Now be advised that the others who have informed you that you will get the top 100 rows in the order specified, and if fewer than 100 rows exist, you will get those, are **entirely correct**.

Hope this helps.  Next time, please consider giving us the schema of the table(s) in your SELECT.

Thanks, 
John.